# RewriteCond ignored in httpd.conf

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Put simply this works in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ https://example.net?u=$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

But when I move it to httpd.conf it does nothing. I have tried in the `directory` directive and that also makes no difference.

As a test the below in httpd.conf does have an affect, it re-directs, but does so to all pages i.e the condition is ignored.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net?u=$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ https://example.net?u=$1 [L,NC,R=301]
> ```
>
> But when I move it to httpd.conf it does nothing.

Because in  a *server* context the `RewriteRule` *pattern* will never match. In a server context the URL-path is root-relative, starting with a slash. In `.htaccess` the URL-path is less the directory-prefix, so never starts with a slash.

> I have tried in the directory directive and that also makes no difference.

That should have worked, providing you included the correct directory path. (And restarted Apache.) However, if you still had a `.htaccess` file that enabled the rewrite engine then this would have overridden the server directives in the `<Directory>` container, so the `<Directory>` directives wouldn't have done anything still.

> As a test the below in httpd.conf does have an affect, it re-directs, but does so to all pages i.e the condition is ignored.
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
> :
> ```

Because in a *server* context the request has not yet been mapped to the filesystem, so `SCRIPT_FILENAME` (or `REQUEST_FILENAME`) does not yet contain the full filesystem path (it simply contains the URL-path), so this condition always evaluates to true (the "URL-path" being tested is not a physical file - which is *probably* correct).

You need to use a look-ahead instead in order to determine the final value. ie. `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}`.

So, in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context you would need to use the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ https://example.net?u=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The `NC` flag is superfluous here.

Comment: Thank you that all makes sense, however I would have not been able to work this out for a long time I'm sure. The final section did the trick.